# Laravel get variable value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

my problem is i have this array :

```
$stockImages = [
    [
        'name' => $large, 
        'type' => 'large', 
        'resolution' => $w.'x'.$h, 
        'size' => $lSize 
    ]
]
```

I want to get this value $w i tried with it

```
{{$stockImages[1]->resolution($w)}}
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Few problems: 1. Array index start from 0, your array has 1 element so should be `$stockImages[0]` 2. You are accessing `resolution` like a property in an object, change to `$stockImages[0]['resolution']` 3. you already concat the $w and $h so it's now  a string, try `explode('x')` to split the w and h

Comment: i tried with it {{$stockImages[0]->resolution(explode('', $w))}} but nothing

Comment: this question is too basic, i suggest you start with a php guide. `->` is object notation and it doesnt apply to arrays.

Comment: as this $stockImages[1]->resolution i receive a value good but i receive the width and height i want only $w width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting too complicated, try this:

```
$stockImages = [[
    'name' => $large, 
    'type' => 'large', 
    'resolution' => 
        [
            'w' => $w, 
            'x' => $h
        ],
    'size' => $lSize 
]];
```

and done, access to width like this way:

```
$stockImages[0]['resolution']['w'];
```

bye <3

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cd60316ace8e386a9e49b22bf95aa7123605b92e